# how to text file item display on multiple spinner from internal storage

Tags: java, android, storage, android-spinner

When I click on write button than create text file in internal storage but when I read them than how to display text file item on spinner. In text file contain name, age, std item when I click read button that item display on a particular spinner.
        In text file item is(name,age,std)
        three spinner(name,age,std)
        when I click on read button all text file item(name,age,std) display on another activity of each spinner.
        problem is how to text file item display each spinner.

```
    Mainactivity.java
    btnWriteSDFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
            btnWriteSDFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Jour=display.getText().toString();
                FILENAME = display.getText().toString();
                if (FILENAME.contentEquals("")){
                    FILENAME = "UNTITLED";
                }

                // write on SD card file data in the text box
                try {
                     FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(FILENAME,MODE_APPEND);
                     fOut.write(display.getText().toString().getBytes());
                     fOut.close();
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file saved",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }
    btnReadSDFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
            btnReadSDFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // write on SD card file data in the text box
                int id = v.getId();
                for (int i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
                    if (id == getResources().getIdentifier("b" + i, "id",
                            "com.example.pp")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.pp."
                                + activities[i]);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }       }); 

list.java   


 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list);
            sp1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            sp2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            sp3=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
            entry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView123);
            getFilesnames();        
        }
        private void getFilesnames() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] filenames=getApplicationContext().fileList();
            List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0;i<filenames.length;i++){
                list.add(filenames[i]);

            }
            /*if(list.size() <= 0) {
                   int i = 0;
                list.add("You string.....");
                }*/

            ArrayAdapter<String> filenameAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
            sp1.setAdapter(filenameAdapter);
        }
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String selectFile = String.valueOf(sp1.getSelectedItem());
            openFile(selectFile);
        }


        private void openFile(String selectFile) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String value = "";
            FileInputStream fis;

            try {
                fis = openFileInput(selectFile);
                byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
                while(fis.read(input) != -1){
                    value += new String(input);
                }
                fis.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            entry.setText(value);

        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting right now?

Comment: no error but all text file item display one spinner.how to all text file item display separately all spinner

Comment: I think first of all you need to fetch all the items , seperated by line, and collect them all in one array and then inflate spinner.

Comment: all item separate by comma in one text file and that item display on all three spinner.i don't no idea about how to display on spinner.any idea or tutorial or code

Comment: Yes, but just tell me, have you read data properly from text file?

Comment: now,only all text file items display on one spinner.how to separate .how to one text file items value display separate three spinner. text file contain(name,age,std) and three spinner(sp1,sp2,sp3).how to name display on sp1,age display on sp2 etc .

Comment: I think you have to save your file data in HashMap. And then add your HashMap into ArrayList, then it will be possible OR you have to create 3 seperate ArrayList for individual.

Comment: how to read txt file item using arraylist and display on spinner,any idea

Comment: I think you are still unclear. I am asking you is that, are you reading file successfully from txt file and stored values perfect or not still?

Comment: all items display by default each spinner not in dropdown list means when I click on read button by defult item direcly display on each spinner.

Comment: how to display item direcly from text file to spinner.how age and std value display on spinner2,spinner3

Comment: Can you send me your project? let me import here and will get back tp you

Comment: how send my project to you?email id

Comment: Ujwala, on my email id : pratikdasa@gmail.com

Comment: pls check email-id,I send project to you

Comment: modify project or not?